# Is it possible to extend the types that are supported by the Phoenix generator?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Is it possible to extend the set of types for a generator? For example if have a custom Ecto type `:money_with_currency` and I want to use that type when generating a new context. This type is not a type that Phoenix supports by default. In a lot of projects I find myself creating a new type and would like to leverage the power of phoenix generators.

### Desired outcome

```bash
mix phx.gen.context Invoicing Package packages price:money_with_currency

# success
```

### Actual outcome

```bash
mix phx.gen.context Invoicing Package packages price:money_with_currency

** (Mix) Unknown type `:money_with_currency` given to generator. The supported types are: array, binary, boolean, date, decimal, enum, float, integer, map, naive_datetime, naive_datetime_usec, references, string, text, time, time_usec, utc_datetime, utc_datetime_usec, uuid
```

Comment: I don't see anything about custom types in the docs: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phx.Gen.Schema.html#module-attributes

Comment: While it’s [not possible](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/a01d10b2e42fdb52365384c0cb6f303e2b21aa66/lib/mix/phoenix/schema.ex#L63) with a default mix generator task, I do not see any particular issue to steal the code from there to create your own task disabling this check and doing whatever else suitable for your custom project(s).